TrueNAS reboots instead of shutting down
I recently installed trueNAS on an old desktop computer. Everything works well except that whenever I shutdown the system it reboots instead. This happens wether I use the web interface to reboot or directly from the console selection the shutdown option (option 11).
I don't know If this is a TrueNAS problem or the BIOS. I have deactivated BIOS options like Wake on LAN and reboot after Power Failure. I provide some pictures of my BIOS config in case it's relevant. What could be the cause or what action could I take to get more information?.
In case is useful the motherboard is an Intel DH67BL. I would be happy to provide any other relevant information.



I happen to have a computer with the same Intel DH67BL motherboard, and when using Windows 10 or various RHEL based Linux distributions don't ever recall seeing this issue. When I select restart or shutdown from an OS the expected behaviour happens. Can you try booting a Linux live ISO from a USB stick and see if shutdown works from the live ISO? That could help to determine if the issue is with the BIOS or trueNAS.

@ChesterGillon Thank you for your attention to my question. I just tried booting into SystemRescue from a USB stick and shuting down. It went as spected so I guess that means that probably it's a problem with TrueNAS
